# React native js. nothing shows when pressing the start button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

I am trying to show or print the duration (timer) when the button start is pressed, but nothing is showing after pressing start. I tried doing Button instead of TouchableOpacity, but still, nothing changed.

```
class Timer extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        count: 0
    }
}
render () {
    const {count} = this.state
    return (
    
        <ScrollView>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            
                <View style={styles.textInputContainer}> 
                
                <Text style={styles.txtHello}>Press start when ready</Text>

          <View style={styles.sep}> 
                 </View>
                
                 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
                    onPress={ () =>    
                        <View style={styles.textInputContainer}> 
                    <Text>
                        <h2> Duration: {count}</h2>
                    </Text>
                        </View>
                    }
                    >
                        
                <Text>start</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>  
         
          </View>
            
          
        </SafeAreaView>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}


componentDidMount(){
    this.myInterval =  setInterval(()=>{
      this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1
        })  
    }, 1000)  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a right way to do it in React. What you would like to do is set a `isVisible` state, change it with your `onPress` props in `Button`/`TouchableOpacity` and finally conditionally show the view you want to display based on that `isVisible` variable. Something like this:

```
class Timer extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        isVisisble:false;
    }
}

render(){
return(
    <View>
    <TouchableOpacity 
     onPress={ () => this.setState((prevState)=>{isVisible:!prevState.isVisible})}
    >                
        <Text>start</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity> 
    {this.state.isVisible && <View></View>} <- Conditional View here

    </View>
)}
```